# Affinity of job in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, cron

What is the default node affinity of a Cron job pod? How can we set it manually?

I have a pod and have set its affinity to node3.

However, the cron job container is still getting completed on node1 all the time when it triggers.

Answer (score 5):

Essentially, in your CronJob spec, the template is the PodSpec and that's where you need to configure the 'Node Affinity'. For example,

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          nodeSelector: 
            name: node3
```

This is assuming the label ️ in your node is `name=node3`.